# Three columns div layout design

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to to design three column div layout with adjustable in deference sizes like showing in image.

[image]

- When desktop size (770px) first column have two div and others have one divs.
- When tablet size (600px) first column have three divs and other have one div. It has two columns.
- When mobile size (less than 600px) all divs have one columns.

Please find the order with colors in image. This is sample code without any proper styles.

HTML:

```
<div class="body">
  <div class="c1">green</div>
  <div class="c2">red</div>
  <div class="c3">yellow</div>
  <div class="c4">blue</div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) {
.c1{ width:100%; min-height:5vh; }
.c2{ width:100%; min-height:5vh; }
.c3{ width:100%; min-height:80vh;}
.c4{ width:100%; min-height:10vh;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
.c1{ width:50%; float:left; }
.c2{ width:50%; float:left; clear:left;}
.c3{ width:50%; position:absolute;right:0;}
.c4{ width:50%; float:left; clear:left;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.c1{ width:25%;}
.c2{ width:25%; float:right;clear:right;}
.c3{ width:50%; left:25%;}
.c4{ width:25%;}
}
.c1{ min-height:20px;}
.c2{ min-height:20px;}
.c3{ min-height:100px;}
.c4{ min-height:20px;}
footer{height:10px; width:100%;}
```

I tried this with order property in CSS, but its not working properly.

Comment: for a css only solution i can only get to this point https://jsfiddle.net/hskhan47/jr180aes/ the modile layout is not perfect yet

Comment: thank you for reply. blue and yellow should be change in second stage in your code. And footer want to add.

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me, please remember that im using inline-blocks so spaces b/w the html div's matter

```
    <div class="body">
        <div class="w container">
            <div class="c3 w s10 ">green</div><div class="c4 w s10">yellow</div>
        </div><div class="c2 w ">red</div>
        <div class="c1 w ">blue</div>

    </div>
    <footer></footer>


<style type="text/css">


.c1 {min-height: 300px;background: blue;width:100px; }
.c2 {min-height: 300px;background: red;width:100px; }
.c3 {min-height: 300px;background: green;width:100px; }
.c4 {min-height: 300px;background: yellow;width:100px; }
footer {background: gray;margin: 0;min-height: 100px;width: 100%;}

.w {display: inline-block;position: relative;vertical-align: top;box-sizing: border-box;}
.s10 {width: 100%;}


body {margin: 0}
@media screen and (min-width: 771px)  { 
    .container {width: 100%;}  
    .c3 {width:30%;margin-right: 40%;}
    .c4,.c1 {width: 30%;}
    .c2 {position: absolute;width: 40%;top: 0;left: 30%;right: 30%;height: 600px}

}

@media screen and (max-width: 770px) and (min-width: 601px)  {  
 .w.container ,.c1  {width: 30%;}
 .w.container > div{width: 100%;}
 .c2.w {width: 70%;}

}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)  {   
    .container,.c1,.c2, .c3 , .c4 {width: 100%;}
    .body {display: flex;flex-direction: column;}

}



</style>
```

Comment: I got problem when we put 900px or higher than 600px to c2 of height. C2 go over the footer. That is what my code problem.

Comment: yes, because .c2 is positioned absolutely, you can increase the height by adding a pseudo element to the body like .body:after {
    content: '';
    padding-top: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
}